# Swift optional chaining doesn't work in closure

Tags: ios, swift

My code looks like this. My class has an optional var

```
var currentBottle : BottleLayer?
```

BottleLayer has a method `jiggle()`.

This code, using optional chaining, compiles fine in my class:

```
self.currentBottle?.jiggle()
```

Now I want to construct a closure that uses that same code:

```
let clos = {() -> () in self.currentBottle?.jiggle()}
```

But I get a compile error:

> Could not find member 'jiggle'

As a workaround I can force unwrapping

```
let clos = {() -> () in self.currentBottle!.jiggle()}
```

or of course I can use full-fledged optional binding, but I'd rather not. I do recognize that optional chaining is just syntactical sugar, but it is hard to see why this syntactical sugar would stop working just because it's in a handler (though there may, of course, be a reason - but it's a surprise in any case).

Perhaps someone else has banged into this and has thoughts about it? Thanks.

Comment: And yes, I've filed a bug report just on the offchance that this is a mistake in the language. But that seems oddly improbable. :)

Comment: I think it *is* a bug, if force unwrapping works, then optional chaining should too

Comment: It's not a bug at all. It's simply because you type your closure explicitly… but with the wrong type (should be `()->()?` and not `()->()`). If you were to remove the explicit type and let Swift infer it for you you can confirm that the type is `Void->Void?`. See my answer below for detailed explanations.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is NOT a bug. It's simply your closure type which is wrong.
The correct type should return an optional `Void` to reflect the optional chaining:

```
let clos = { ()->()? in currentBottle?.jiggle() }
```

---

### The problem in details:

- You declare your closure as a closure that returns `Void` (namely `->()`).
- But, do remember that, as like every time you use optional chaining, the return type of the whole expression is **of optional type**. Because your closure can **either return `Void`** if `currentBottle` do exists… **or `nil`** if it doesn't!

So the correct syntax is to make your closure return a `Void?` (or `()?`) instead of a simple `Void`

```
class BottleLayer {
    func jiggle() { println("Jiggle Jiggle") }
}
var currentBottle: BottleLayer?
currentBottle?.jiggle() // OK
let clos = { Void->Void? in currentBottle?.jiggle() } // Also OK
let clos = { () -> ()? in currentBottle?.jiggle() } // Still OK (Void and () are synonyms)
```

Note: if you had let Swift infer the correct type for you instead of explicitly forcing it, it would have fixed the issue for you:

```
// Even better: type automatically inferred as ()->()? — also known as Void->Void?
let clos = { currentBottle?.jiggle() }
```

---

[EDIT]

### Additional trick: directly assign the optional chaining to a variable

You can even assign the function directly to a variable, like so:

```
let clos2 = currentBottle?.jiggle // no parenthesis, we don't want to call the function, just refer to it
```

Note that the type of `clos2` (which is not explicitly specified here and is thus inferred automatically by Swift) in this case is **not** `Void->Void?` — namely a function that returns either `nil` or `Void`) as in the previous case — but **is `(Void->Void)?`**, which is the type for "an **optional** function of type `Void->Void`".

This means that `clos2` itself is "either `nil` or is a function returning `Void`". To use it, you could once again use optional chaining, simply like that:

```
clos2?()
```

This will evaluate to `nil` and do nothing if `clos2` is itself `nil` (likely because `currentBottle` is itself nil)… and execute the closure — thus the `currentBottle!.jiggle()` code — and return `Void` if `clos2` is non-nil (likely because `currentBottle` itself is non-nil).

The return type of `clos2?()` itself is indeed `Void?`, as it returns either nil or Void.

Doing the distinction between `Void` and `Void?` may seem pointless (after all, the `jiggle` function does not return anything in either case), but it let you do powerful stuff like testing the `Void?` in an `if` statement to check if the call actually did happen (and returned `Void` namely nothing) or didn't happen (and return `nil`):

```
if clos2?() { println("The jiggle function got called after all!") }
```

---

[EDIT2] As you (@matt) pointed out yourself, this other alternative has one other major difference: it evaluates `currentBottle?.jiggle` at the time that expression got affected to `clos2`. So if `currentBottle` is `nil` at that time, `clos2` will be `nil`… even if `currentBottle` got a non-nil value later.

Conversely, `clos` is affected to the closure itself, and the optional chaining is only evaluated each time `clos` is called, so it will evaluate to `nil` if `currentBottle` is nil… but will be evaluated to non-nil and will call `jiggle()` if we call `clos()` at a later time at which point `currentBottle` became non-nil.

Comment: This actually made my code even more awesome than it already was.

Comment: You can do even more awesome stuff, like assigning the variable directly to the function (function and closures have the same type in Swift). Namely `let clos2 = currentBottle?.jiggle`. But note that if you do that, you obtain something a little bit different than `clos`: you don't obtain a `Void->Void?` but a `(Void->Void)?`, namely an "optional function". Instead of having "a function that returns either `nil` or `Void`", you get "Either `nil` or a function that return `Void`". You can then call it with `clos2?()` (which won't do anything if currentBottle thus clos2 were nil)

Comment: I edited my answer to explain this additional trick in more details.

Comment: The second trick is cool but for other reasons I actually want the closure, not merely a function reference. There's a big difference between evaluating `currentBottle?` now (to pass thru it and pull out the method ref) and later (to pass thru it _at the time we call the closure_, when it may be a different object).

Comment: I feel that some answers on SO are better and deeper than 10 pages of Apple's reference book...

Comment: If you want your closure to actually return `Void` and not `Void?` you can add an extra `return` at the end of the closure. Closures with only one expression and no `return` statement will assume a `return` statement in front of the expression (= will implicitly return the return value of that single expression). That's why your closure implicitly want to return the return value of `currentBottle?.jiggle()` with is of type `Void?`. Explicitly adding a  `return` at the end of your closure to prevent the implicit return of the `currentBottle?.jiggle()` return value and "return Void" instead.

Comment: @matt I didn't think about that, but you're right, the second trick evaluates the `currentBottle` during the chaining at the time we affect the function to `clos2`, leading to a `nil` function if `currentBottle` is `nil`… at that time, even if it got non-nil later. Whereas the closure will defer that evaluation and reevaluate `currentBottole` each time it is called. Good point!

Comment: Recall that the closure was inherent in the original question. If you throw that away, you throw away both it (the closer) and the thing that was causing the original problem (the inability to use the optional chain inside it). So, while the additional trick is interesting and cool, it is irrelevant - I already knew that optional chaining worked _not_ in a closure, and your second trick, even though you call the variable `clos`, has no closure.

Comment: I know. The second trick was only to show that we can affect a function to a constant, as an additional info, but was not relevant to your original question, you're right. PS: In Swift functions are just named closures (they have the same type and are interchangeable) so strictly speaking, `clos2` is a closure (even if we generally use the "function" vocabulary for it). Like `*` is an operator (of type `(T,T)->T`) which can also be considered a closure equivalent to `{ (x:T,y:T)->T in x*y }`

Comment: @AliSoftware, in Swift2.0, there's no compile error at all for original code, how to explain that?

Comment: I'm guessing probably because in Swift 2.0 they fixed the compiler so that, if the closure's return type is `Void`, the compiler will ignore it for you (so that you won't need to add an extra `return` at the end of the closure to force returning nothing)

Answer (score 7):

```
let closure = { () -> () in
    self.currentBottle?.jiggle()
    return
}
```

Otherwise the compiler thinks the result of that statement should be returned from the closure and it realizes there is a mismatch between `()` (return type) and the optional returned by the statement (`Optional<Void>`). By adding an explicit `return`, the compiler will know that we don't want to return anything.

The error message is wrong, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, another approach. This is because closures in Swift have *Implicit Returns from Single-Expression Closures*. Because of the optional chain, your closure has a return type of `Void?`, so:

```
let clos = {() -> Void? in self.currentBottle?.jiggle()}
```

Answer (score 0):

Letting the closure type be inferred seems to work as well.

```
let clos2 = { currentBottle?.jiggle() }
clos2() // does a jiggle
```

But I'm pretty sure this is just the compiler assigning a type of `() -> ()?`