# Optional chaining in Swift Closure where return type has to be Void

Tags: ios, swift, closures, ios8, option-type

I am creating a doubly-linked-list of scripts (`MSScript`s) that are supposed to have their own `run()` implementation, and they call the next script (`rscript`) when they're ready . One of the scripts I'd like to create is just a delay. It looks like this:

```
class DelayScript : MSScript
{
    var delay = 0.0
    override func run() {
        let delay = self.delay * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)
        let time = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delay))
        let weakSelf = self
        dispatch_after(time, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            weakSelf.rscript?.run()
            Void.self
        }
    }
    init(delay: Double) {
        super.init()
        self.delay = delay
    }
}
```

Where `rscript` is the next script to run. The problem is that if I remove the last line of the dispatch_after, it doesn't compile, and that's because of [the changed return type of `run()` from optional chaining](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24125328/swift-optional-chaining-doesnt-work-in-closure). I randomly decided to insert `Void.self` and it fixed the problem, but I have no idea why.

What is this `Void.self`, and is it the right solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Optional chaining wraps whatever the result of the right side is inside an optional. So if `run()` returned `T`, then `x?.run()` returns `T?`. Since `run()` returns `Void` (a.k.a. `()`), that means the whole optional chaining expression has type `Void?` (or `()?`).

When a closure has only one line, the contents of that line is implicitly returned. So if you only have that one line, it is as if you wrote `return weakSelf.rscript?.run()`. So you are returning type `Void?`, but `dispatch_async` needs a function that returns `Void`. So they don't match.

One solution is to add another line that explicitly returns nothing:

```
dispatch_after(time, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    weakSelf.rscript?.run()
    return
}
```

Comment: In Swift 1.2 (Xcode 6.3 beta) the explicit return statement is not needed anymore here. From the release notes: *"Unannotated single-expression closures with non-Void return types can now be used in Void contexts."*.