# Swift closure return type error

Tags: xcode, swift, closures

I've got the following code:

```
weak var weakSelf: foo? = self

NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserverForName(NSApplicationWillTerminateNotification, object: nil, queue: nil, usingBlock: { (notification: NSNotification!) -> () in
        weakSelf?.invalidate()
    })

func invalidate(){}
```

I keep getting the following error: *Cannot convert the expression's type '(@lvalue NSString!, object: NilLiteralConvertible, queue: NilLiteralConvertible, (NSNotification!) -> ())' to type '()'*

I understand what the error means, but I don't understand why I'm getting the error when the return type of *invalidate* function is nil, and so it the block's. Also how should I correct it. If I try `println("message")` then the error dissipates, so am I not allowed to call method in a closure?

Comment: try putting in an empty `return`

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25351925/optional-chaining-in-swift-closure-where-return-type-has-to-be-void. – And yes, adding an explicit `return` statement is a solution.

Comment: Btw, this problem does not occur anymore with Swift 1.2.