# Error while passing closure as a parameter of function

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have created one global function which is taking closure as it's one of parameter. See my code below,

```
func delayExecute(delay:Double, task:()->Void) {
    var queue: dispatch_queue_t
    queue =  dispatch_get_main_queue()
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delay * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))), queue, { task()})
}
```

I am calling this function from ViewDidLoad of controller.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    progressHud = MBProgressHUD.showHUDAddedTo(self.view, animated: true)

    delayExecute(2.0, {
        self.progressHud?.hide(true)
    })
}
```

Important portion of viewDidLoad is calling to `delayExecute` function. It is giving me an error : `error: cannot invoke 'hide' with an argument list of type '(FloatLiteralConvertible, () -> () -> $T2)'`

From below experiments or trial and error I concluded that this is a single line closure so, compiler is implicitly returning a value of  `self.progressHud?.hide(true)` which is "void" and it is creating problem.

I want to know following things,

- What is the problem in calling snippet?
- What is the right way to correct it?

**Tried following things and those are working but don't know why**,

```
delayExecute1(2.0, {
        println("")
        self.progressHud?.hide(true)
    })
```

Only added `println` statement in that closure.

```
 delayExecute1(2.0, {
        println(self.progressHud?.hide(true))
    })
```

Captured whole statement in `println`

```
delayExecute(2.0, {
        self.progressHud!.hide(true)
    })
```

Used `!`(forcefully unwrap) instead of `?`(Optional chaining)

Comment: Or this one: [Swift optional chaining doesn't work in closure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24125328/swift-optional-chaining-doesnt-work-in-closure)

Comment: Agree. This is a duplicate. So, what should be my action for this question

Comment: No action needed on your question. Compare http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261948/deleting-questions-after-being-flagged-as-duplicate-or-when-the-question-is-answ : *" ... don't delete duplicates. Unless you really just didn't put any effort at all into searching"*